# How can I implement a '-Help' switch in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I'm a PowerShell user for some time, but im not sure how to implement a `-Help` switch for my PoSh script(s).

The scripts have already a built-in help which can be retrieved by using `Get-Help myscript.ps1`.

The scripts have multiple parameters which are documented. I would like to add another parameter `-Help` to call `Get-Help` on the script itself.

I would like to offer an additional interface to get the help page(s). It's also common to use `-h`/`--help` on Linux systems in alternative to `man <cmd>`.

I already tested it with functions but the function's name is fixed and known; a script can be renamed ...

```
#
# .SYNOPSIS
# help text
#

[CmdLetBinding()]
param(
  [switch]$Help = $false
)

if ($Help)
{ Get-Help  <me>
  return
}

Write-Host "other statements"
```

What should I insert for `<me>`?

Comment: You don't need to add a -Help parameter. Just use [comment-based help](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847834.aspx).

Comment: Please read my question again. The script has already a comment based help. I don't want to rewirte/duplicate  the help content. I want to display it when a user calls my script with `-Help`.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I just don't see the purpose of what you want to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can make good use of `$MYINVOCATION.InvocationName` here :

```
function Test-Function {
    Param([Switch]
        $Help = $false
    )
    if($Help) {
        "help mode : function name is $($MYINVOCATION.InvocationName)"
    } else {
        "normal process"
    }
}

Test-Function -Help
```

`Get-Help` has yet to be called with the function name, and I'll let you lose some hair on this (failed with `.`) !