# how to handle -? help parameter in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'd like to create in my PS1 script a `-?` (help parameter), which will display some info, and description of all accepted parameters.

Almost every command in powershell has the `-?` parameter, but I did not find any build-in decent way to handle this parameter.

The only way I found, is using `-?` as `switch` (Flag) parameter, and display a long text to describe how to use my script.

Is there a nicer (build-in?) way to use the `-?` parameter, maybe combine it with `helpmessage` ? Maybe like python handle arguments?

Comment: I think you are looking for [comment based help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comment_based_help?view=powershell-6)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I implement a '-Help' switch in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927153/how-can-i-implement-a-help-switch-in-powershell)